# Why does it give error on bulk insert?

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server Management Studio, I try to do a bulk insert from a file in the local machine. I get that error:
*Cannot bulk load because the file "F:\tick_bulk.txt" could not be opened. Operating system error code 3(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105).*
The file is not opened anywhere..
Why does it give that error?

Comment: 3 is path not found. The path you provide must be a path that the *server* can resolve. Does the account that the server is running under have access to an `F` drive, and does that `F` drive contain such a file?

Comment: This is my fault..The SQL Server is not running on my local machine, so it can not access to my local folder.I will try to use the network path.

Answer (score 1):

Your path is a local path, in your PC,
Must set path from the server!

to be sure that the path correct, login to the realy server (Server Contains SQL database) and try open the file from there.

NOTE: check also the file permisions.